# Clear objects properties by button click

Tags: javascript, css, events, button

There are 5 boxes, which can be changed from 'white'<->'yellow' colors by mouse events (mouseover, mouseout and click). There is also a blue area with text displaying the level of the clicked box.
After clicking into the third box, I got 'hard level' text in blue area and 3 boxes color in yellow.

What I need is to return it to the default level ('easy level' and first box in yellow only) by clicking the reset button.

I have been trying do this like this , but it isn't working:

```
resetBtn = document.querySelector('#update');
```

and eventlistener:

```
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', highlightStars(`#star1`), true)
```

Here is an example:

```js
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changeStars, false);
    
    const resetBtn = document.querySelector('#update');
    
    /* Change level of the game depending on user choice */
    
    function changeStars() {
     /* Displaying level text inside blue box */
     const updateAltText = currentLevelIndex => {
      let levelText = document.querySelector('#level-text');
      /* 'currentLevelIndex + 1' replaces event 'currentElement' */
      levelText.textContent = document.querySelector(`#star${currentLevelIndex + 1}`).alt;
     }
     
     /* Captcha level number - default is 1 */
     const getNumber = str => Number(str.match(/\d+/)[0]) || 1;
     
     /* Star index is always one number lower than level number (indexing rules) */
     const getStarIndex = event => getNumber(event.target.id) - 1;
     
     let stars = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
     
      const handleStarClick = event => {
      /* FIRST - blocking possibility to change star behaviour by mouse events */
      gameLevel.removeEventListener('mouseover', highlightStars);
      gameLevel.removeEventListener('mouseout', highlightStars);
    
      /* SECOND - making all needed star with yellow color */
      const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
      for (let i = 0; i <= getStarIndex(event); i++) {
       stars[i].classList.add('yellow');
      }
       };
    
     const highlightStars = event => {
      const starIndex = getStarIndex(event);
      updateAltText(starIndex);
      for (let i = 1; i <= starIndex; i++) {
       const star = document.querySelector(`#star${i + 1}`);
       star.classList.toggle('yellow');
      }
     };
    
     // resetBtn.addEventListener('click', highlightStars(`#star1`), true);
     
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', updateAltText(0), true);

     const gameLevel = document.querySelector('.game-level');
     gameLevel.addEventListener("mouseover", highlightStars);
     gameLevel.addEventListener("mouseout", highlightStars);
     gameLevel.addEventListener('click', handleStarClick, {once: true});
    }
```

```css
    .stars {
      display: flex;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 500px;
    }
    
    input[type='image'] {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border: thin solid black;
    }
    
    .yellow {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .game-level {
      display: flex;
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .level-block {
      display: flex;
      width: 200px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: 1px solid hsl(217, 86%, 50%);
      border-radius: 25px;
      background-color: hsl(212, 29%, 80%);
    }
    
    .level-block > span {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .reset {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="stars">
      <div class="game-level">
        <input type="image" class="star yellow" id="star1" src="" width="60" alt="easy level">
        <input type="image" class="star" id="star2" src="" width="60" alt="normal level">
        <input type="image" class="star" id="star3" src="" width="60" alt="hard level">
        <input type="image" class="star" id="star4" src="" width="60" alt="very hard level">
        <input type="image" class="star" id="star5" src="" width="60" alt="impossible level">
      </div>
      <div class="level-block">
        <span id="level-text">Easy level</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="reset" id="update" value="RESET">
```

Comment: Your `highlightStarts` function takes an event as a parameter, not a string, so passing `'start1'` shouldn't be expected to work. What you can do is change that function to take a number instead, the star id, then you could pass `1` to it when the reset button is clicked. Then instead of passing `highlightStarts` as the handler for the events, you can pass `event => highlightStars(event.target.id)`.

Comment: What about making default text 'easy level' after clicking reset button? I put `resetBtn.addEventListener('click', updateAltText(0), true)` and didn't take `levelText.textContent = document.querySelector(`#star1`).alt;` which should give me 'easy level' (from the `<input image alt='easy level'>` parameter).

Comment: What I'm understanding you want, is for clicking the reset button to do the same thing as clicking easy level, correct?

Comment: After click any box there should be possibility to return to default level which is level 1- only first box has yellow color and text 'easy level' (in blue area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following demo uses JavaScript for click events only, all mouse events (ie hover) are pure CSS. The reset behavior simply removes `.active` class on all buttons then adds `.active` class to the first button. Instead of the first button title being displayed after a reset -- the reset button title: `"Game Reset"` is displayed, it might be a little confusing for users if there's no confirmation of a reset. Other behavior is included in demo that is logical and consistent such as toggling, hovering to a temporary state and clicking for a persistent state etc. Details are commented in demo.

```js
// Reference the form
const stars = document.forms.stars;

/*
Register the form to the click event -- when a click occurs anywhere on or within the form, callback function twinkle() is
called
*/
stars.onclick = twinkle;

/**
//A -- twinkle passes a reference to the Event Object... (e)
//B1 - Two Event Object properties are used to reference:
          The tag the was clicked by user: event.target 
          The tag registered to the event: event.currentTarget
//B2 - The HTMLFormElement property: .elements collects all form
       controls into a Live HTML Collection (aka NodeList)
//C -- ui.star is a Collection of form controls with [name=star] 
       The brackets [] and spread operator ... converts the  
       NodeList into an Array
//D -- Reference the message tag. If the clicked tag was the reset
       button -- for...of loop iterates through each [name=star]
       and removes the class .active from all [name=star]
//E1 - Next add .active class to the default button
//E2 - Set the legend.message text to the value of clicked button
       [title] attribute...
~~~~~~~
//F -- ...But if a button.star was clicked, a check to verify if 
       clicked tag has the .active class -- then a for...of
       loop identical to the one described in line D is used to
       remove any .active class.
//G -- After there are no .active, the Boolean declared in line F
       determines whether the clicked tag gets the .active class 
       and its [title] attribute displayed or not
*/
function twinkle(e) {
  const active = e.target;
  const ui = e.currentTarget.elements;
  const starZ = [...ui.star];
  const msg = document.querySelector(".message");
  if (active.matches("#clear")) {
    for (let star of starZ) {
      star.classList.remove("active");
    }
    ui.star1.classList.add('active');
    msg.textContent = active.title;
  } else if (active.matches(".star")) {
    let status = active.classList.contains("active");
    for (let star of starZ) {
      star.classList.remove("active");
    }
    if (!status) {
      active.classList.add("active");
      msg.textContent = active.title;
    } else {
      active.classList.remove("active");
      msg.textContent = "";
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 small-caps 2.5vw/1 Arial
}

.levels {
  display: table;
  width: 96%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid hsl(217, 86%, 50%);
  border-radius:4px;
}

.message {
  display: table-caption;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 6vh;
  margin: 0 auto 2vh;
  padding: 0.5vh 0;
  border: 1px solid hsl(217, 86%, 50%);
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  background-color: hsla(212, 29%, 80%, 25%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #0078D7;
}

#clear {
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#clear:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

/*
Flex is applied to the button.star'S parent tag so the order
property can be utilized.
*/
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70vw;
}

.star {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  width: 16vw;
  height: 24vh;
  border: thin solid black;
  background: #DDD;
  font-size: 3.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
GSC (General Sibling Combinator: ~ ) provides highlighting across 
multiple buttons.
Exp. 5 buttons: [-] [-] [X] ~ [>] ~ [>]
*/
.star.active,
.star:hover,
.star.active ~ .star,
.star:hover ~ .star {
  background: gold;
}

/*
HTML layout has button.star in reverse order. Applying order to
each button rectifies the order by APPEARING in order while the
HTML structure remains reversed.
*/
#star1 {
  order: 1;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

#star2 {
  order: 2;
}

#star3 {
  order: 3;
}

#star4 {
  order: 4;
}

#star5 {
  order: 5;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

#star1:hover,
#star1.active {
  color: #5BC0DE;
}

#star2:hover,
#star2.active {
  color: #FF1C8D;
}

#star3:hover,
#star3.active {
  color: #00D800;
}

#star4:hover,
#star4.active {
  color: #0000D5;
}

#star5:hover,
#star5.active {
  color: #D50000;
}
```

```html
<form id="stars" action="">
  <fieldset name="levels" class="levels">
    <legend class="message">Novice</legend>
    <button id="clear" type="reset" title="Game Reset">&#128260;</button>
    <section class="flex">
      <button id="star5" name='star' class="star" title="Master">&#128976;</button>
      <button id="star4" name='star' class="star" title="Expert">&#128972;</button>
      <button id="star3" name='star' class="star" title="Advanced">&#128970;</button>
      <button id="star2" name='star' class="star" title="Intermediate">&#128966;</button>
      <button id="star1" name='star' class="star active" title="Novice">&#128962;</button>
    </section>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```